# Scala Idiomatic and Fastest way for consuming multiple web services and merging output

Tags: scala, web-services, parallel-processing, functional-programming, future

I have a Scala app that consumes multiple Data sources and merges the combined output, the app invokes multiple HTTP calls in parallel and waits for their results, when all are resolved it merges their output into a single result object and sends the response back as a Scala Future. The code:

```
val providers = getProviders()
val futures = for (p <- providers) yield searchSource(p, req)
val result = waitAll(futures)
val emptyList = Option(ProductList(Vector.empty, ListSummary(0, 0, 0)))

result.map { x =>
  x.foldLeft(emptyList)((r, c) => {
    if (c.isSuccess) ProductList.merge(r, c.get) else r
  })
}
```

It first gets a list of Strings of providers, then triggers calls to each in parallel in searchSource.

The searchSource function itself returns `Future[Option[ProductList]]`

The method waits for all Futures to complete, for that it calls waitAll function:

```
  protected def waitAll[T](futures: Seq[Future[T]])(implicit ec: CustomExecutionContext): Future[Seq[Try[T]]] =
    Future.sequence(lift(futures))

  protected def lift[T](futures: Seq[Future[T]])(implicit ec: CustomExecutionContext): Seq[Future[Try[T]]] =
    futures.map(_.map { Success(_) }.recover { case t => Failure(t) })
```

After waiting for all futures to complete, it aggregates the results into a single composite object and returns it as a future. For that I use the foldLeft function.

Are there any "official" Monadic/Idiomatic ways for solving this type of problem or are there any performance optimised examples for this type of use-case?

Comment: Do you mean how to turn Seq[Future[t]] to Future[Seq[t]]? Aside for Future.sequence,you can also use akka stream to do that,which can be distributed

Comment: First, have a look at [cats traverse](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/traverse.html). Second, instead of `Future`s you might consider [fs2](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2)

Comment: @Yaneeve `fs2` is a streaming solution, not a `Future` replacement. Perhaps Monix `Task[A]` and cats-effect `IO[A]` are more suitable here if we're looking for lazily evaluated async computations. BTW, idiomatic and fastest are orthogonal requirements.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov true enough. I envisioned "consumes multiple Data sources" as implying streams of data

Answer (score 0):

Sure. It's a common pattern, and using `cats-effect`'s `IO` instead of `Future` really helps (there are other options too). For example, you might implement something like this (I'm being explicit about types for clarity):

```
def searchSource(provider: String, request: Request[_]): IO[Option[ProductList]] = ???

val result: IO[List[Option[ProductList]]] = 
  providers.traverse[IO, Option[ProductList]](p => searchSource(p, req))
```

Note that `traverse` is essentially the same as `map` followed by `sequence`. You can then do whatever you want within your `result` `IO` program (e.g. `map` over it, etc.) to transform it into the final result you desire. At the end of your program, you can do this:

```
result.attempt.unsafeRunSync() //Either[Throwable, List[Option[ProductList]]]
```

For error handling, check out `IO`'s `handleErrorWith` method. You can handle errors at the `searchSource` level and/or at the `result` level, as they are both `IO`s.